# Import error when running django server

Tags: django, socket.io

I get the following error when I try to run `python manage.py runserver_socketio`

`ImportError: cannot import name SocketIOServer`

When I run `python` and `help("modules")` the socket module appears to be there. How can I determine what "SocketIOServer" needs to be changed to in `from socket import SocketIOServer`?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: is it in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: have you tried running just the python shell?

Comment: @karthikr `django_socketio` is

Comment: go to shell - `./manage.py shell` and see if you can import `SocketIOServer`

Comment: This gives me `ImportError: No module named SocketIOServer`

Comment: @MattWritesCode I have and it gives me the same error when I try `from socket import SocketIOServer`

Comment: It seems you're confusing the socket module from the stdlib (that ships with Python) with something that adds socket.io support to django. Those have nothing to do with each other. I would guess you didn't install django-socketio correctly. See the instructions at https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio

Answer (score 1):

ERROR : "ImportError: cannot import name SocketIOServer"

The error is in the command file

> runserver_socketio.py

located in the folder

> site-packages/django_socketio/management/commands/

In the line 13 it says:

> from socketio import SocketIOServer

Then I fixed it to:

> from socketio.server import SocketIOServer

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install django-socketio (gevent gives a basic system, but for django written a separate add-on) or check access rights